# Python RegEx: Extract all possible types of chars from string and automatically create a RegEx pattern based on sample

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I want automatically analyse string for all present types of chars and also create a RegEx pattern based on a column with a sample template.
So that later any string which is related to this pattern could be cleaned by only allowed chars and then aligned with pattern.

For example samples could be:

"A111AA1" - means that all possible chars: only letters and didgits; pattern should be: first letter, then 3 digits, followed by 2 letters and 1 digit.

"11AA-111A" - means that possible chars: letters, digits, hyphen/dash; pattern: 2 digits, 2 letters, dash, 3 digits, 1 letter.

Is it possible without manual if-else hardcoding? Unique patterns could be > 1000.

Thanks.

#### Update

Regarding extracting all possible chars in string I've created following function. It creates RegEx with existing (allowed) chars in pattern.
If you know better method, let me know.

```
def extractCharsFromPattern(pattern: str) -> str:
    allowedChars = []
    
    # Convert string to set of chars
    pattern = ''.join(set(pattern))
    
    # Letters
    if re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]", pattern):
        allowedChars.append("a-zA-Z")
        pattern = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z]", "", pattern)
    # Digits
    if re.findall(r"[0-9]", pattern):
        allowedChars.append("0-9")
        pattern = re.sub(r"[0-9]", "", pattern)    
    # Special chars
    allowedChars.append(pattern)
    
    # Prepare in regex format
    allowedChars = "[" + "".join(allowedChars) + "]"
    
    return allowedChars
```

Comment: Please show us how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I did manual regex for each template, like '[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}' but it's impossible for such amount of patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your patterns are that simplistic then of course you can match on that to get a regex, for example:

```
patterns = ["A111AA1", "11AA-111A"]
for pattern in patterns:
    re_pattern = ''.join([r'\d' if c.isdigit() else r'[a-zA-Z]' if c.isalpha() else r'-' if c=='-' else '???' for c in pattern])
    print (pattern, '-->', re_pattern)

A111AA1   --> [a-zA-Z]\d\d\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d
11AA-111A --> \d\d[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-\d\d\d[a-zA-Z]
```

From your comments, if you just want a character class, you'd chain it all together. Here is an example one-line but based on your requirements you'd put it in a function:

```
>>> s="AA-22"
>>> r = ('['                                   # start of character class
  +  ('a-z' if re.search(r'[a-z]', s) else '') # have a lowercase?
  + ('A-Z' if re.search(r'[A-Z]', s) else '')  # have an uppercase?
  + ('0-9' if re.search(r'[0-9]', s) else '')  # have a number?
  + ('-' if re.search(r'-', s) else '')        # have a dash
  + ']'                                        # end of character class
  +  '{' + str(len(s)) + '}'                   # enforce a length?
)
# '[A-Z0-9-]{5}'
>>> re.search(r, "BB-44").group(0)
# 'BB-44'
```

Comment: Unfortunately not that simplistic, but I got your point, thanks!
Any ideas how I can extract all types of chars from string?

Comment: @Oleksii what o you mean "all types of characters" ? You only have a number, dash, and letter in your question?

Comment: Yes, but it's just sample, it could be patterns with dots, space, etc. So what I mean - to extract all possible/allowed chars according to the pattern. Check my update of the question.  
For example: pattern = "A1-AA-1A". Means that string should contain only digits, letters and dash, all other chars removed ( re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9-]',"",string) )

Comment: @Oleksii sorry I don't follow: could you give an example or so of input/output?

Comment: Yep. Input - string pattern (one of a many), where "A" represents any letter, "1" - any digit, etc. Output - RegEx, which will filter only chars which are allowed in input pattern.
Example: 
Input: string pattern = "A1-AA-1A".  
According to the pattern, string can contain only letters, digits mand dash. 
Output: r'[^a-zA-Z0-9-]'

Comment: @Oleksii see update, but I think your function in the question already does that. If you want to add lengths it'd need more logic.